# Invalid Argument error while writing to a file in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been using the following function to write files and it has always been working.

However, it throws an invalid argument error after successful for the first few right now. Very confused. There is nothing special about the file name. I'm using Python 3.7. Thank you.

```
def write_output(filename, cleaned_text, flag = 'w+'):
    with open(filename, flag, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as outfile:
        outfile.write(cleaned_text)

with open(filename, flag, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as outfile:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 
'D:\\EDGAR_DATA_SEAGATE\\10K_filings_HTM_clean\\2016\\8818_Avery Dennison Corp_2016-02-24_10- 
 K_0001047469-16-010376_clean.txt'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you try to use something simple like `r"C:\abc.txt"` as file name?

Comment: I restarted the computer and reconnected the external hard drive, and it worked. Nothing is wrong with the code. Probably due to a connection issue with the external hard drive.